# performance issues in ASP.NET Membership

Tags: asp.net

I am working with Aspnet membership, and I have stored users information in membership related data e.g. userid and password stored in Aspnet_Membership table, member profile like firstname, lastname, surname, dob etc in aspnet_profile table.

Now I need to add a search panel in my webpage. This search panel contains searching parameters like firstname, lastname and joining date etc. as per this searching parameters I need to search users from profile and user's last login information. I used profilecommon and profilebase class for retrieving this data. But it is seriously slow.  The system takes  at least 2 minutes to find data as per parameters from 70 records.

Please help to resolve this program.

Comment: Have you created Indexes in your database tables? Can you post the SQL query you're using for search?

Comment: yes, Indexes were created. And btw, this tables are created using aspnet_regiis. So Do i need to generate indexes explicitly?

Comment: Could you explain this more: _"to findind data as per parameters from 70 records. "_ What parameters, what data and what queries? 70 records mean you have 70 users?

Comment: yes, 70 records means 70 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should retrieve the membership and profile information within the stored procedure, and not using any of the code-based classes to get the name.  It won't perform well with extracting profile information per user.

Comment: You are right. I have used code based classes to get name and other information of profile.
But aspnet_profiles saves data in serialized manner. So do you have any stored procedure which could be useful to resolve this case?

Comment: I don't have anything off-hand; I think people wrote utilities to handle this, or you could also look around for an alternative provider.  Some people came up with alternative profile databases, where each value is a row in the table.

Comment: I personally am a fan of not using profile, but using a separate table in my database for storing all this information in.  It makes it a lot easier (say a Users table with a field for first/last name, etc.).  This way, you can easily extract the info, and link this table record to the membership provider through the provideruserkey field.